# How to upload image with login token on server in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, web-services, parsing

In my application I take image in image view an after click on aButton it goes to LoginViewController where user has to fill its username and password.i got login token there are some parameter and condition like :

```
Method: PMac_LogIn  
Parameter: mailaddress String with @   
password String     
Return: If ok, then you receive a loginToken. (> 0)   
If not ok, then loginToken < 0   
-1 = user not found  
-2 = wrong password   
When you can not reach the server, you have to inform the user in dialog, with “Server not available”. In the cases -1 or -2 you should inform the user.
```

I used WSDL web service and don't know how to do login but already access web service.what will be the conditional code.

here is my code:

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

```
NSString *theXML1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
NSLog(@"theXML: \n%@",theXML1);
[theXML1 release];

if( xmlParser )
{
    [xmlParser release];
}

xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
[xmlParser setDelegate: self];
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
[xmlParser parse];

[connection release];
[webData release];

UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"User Not Exist" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
[errorAlert release];
```

}

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"HelloResult"])
    {
        if(!soapResults)
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
        recordResults = TRUE;
    }
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if( recordResults )
    {
        [soapResults appendString: string];
    }
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"HelloResult"])
    {
        recordResults = FALSE;

        [soapResults release];
        soapResults = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//add jsonkit to project 
//top of your file
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1
//your login url
#define kloginJSONURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/login_script.php?"] //2 LOGIN LINK

//supose you have 2 text fields named UserName and UserPassword
NSString *stringLOGINquery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@username=%@&parola=%@",kloginJSONURL, UserName.text, UserPassword.text];
NSURL *COMBINAT = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[stringLOGINquery stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 //add this
//async queue with selector
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
     NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:COMBINAT];
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
     withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
          NSLog(@"obiect date login%@", data);
});

//now your selector
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
//check if json exists then suppose your json returns a Login key:
if(json) {
NSString *loginToken  =[json objectForKey:@"Login"];
if ([loginToken isEqualToString:@""]) {
//your prompt -> token fail
} else if ([loginToken isEqualToString:@"-1"] || [loginToken isEqualToString:@"-2"] ) {
// fail
} else if ([loginToken isEqualToString:@"Succes"]  {    
// is ok
//here you can implement if length of loginToken > 0 but keep in mind it must be != -1 -2 so write something like this
int LenghtloginToken = [loginToken length]; 
if(LenghtloginToken >0 && ! loginToken isEqualToString:@"-1"] || ! [loginToken isEqualToString:@"-2"]) {
//success
}
```

Regarding your question about sending to another view ->
I think you must start reading some tutorials. This is a trivial question.

Comment: i m using xml parsing so just want to know what how to access login token is above code will run for login token?

Comment: login token = 0 then it should be go to another view controller

Answer (score 0):

```
int LenghtloginToken = [elementName length];
if(LenghtloginToken >0 && (! [elementName isEqualToString:@"-1"] || ! [elementName isEqualToString:@"-2"])) {
 //success
 NSLog(@"success%@", elementName);
}
```

Keep in mind start reading some good tutorials about basic stuff in Objective C.

Comment: int LenghtloginToken = [elementName length];
    if(LenghtloginToken >0 && ! [elementName isEqualToString:@"-1"] || ! [elementName isEqualToString:@"-2"])

Comment: please help ... is there any code for nslog so that i can see what is i got